# Making a biagram table from Corpus

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus

i am trying to make a biagram table from a corpus with a text file which contains 100 sentences but i am unable to do it. right now i only have code with showing how many sentences that text file has. I am new to machine translation and couldnt work it out from NLTK packages. Can anyone help? thanks

```
from nltk.corpus.reader import WordListCorpusReader

reader = nltk.corpus.PlaintextCorpusReader('.', ['100sentence.txt'])

print ("The number of sentences =", len(reader.sents()))
```

basically what i want to do is make a biagram table from my txt file and being able to count words that i want from the text file

Comment: The nltk has a `bigrams` method that you can use: `nltk.bigrams(reader.words())`. But how does a bigram table allow you to count words? Please clarify what you intend to do with it.